# Access out of scope variables without passing them?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to access variables outside their class?

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
    int x;
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    int get_x()
    {
        //somehow access MyClass1's variable x without 
        //passing it as an argument and return it.
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyClass1 obj1;
    obj1.x = 5;
    MyClass2 obj2;
    std::cout << obj2.get_x();
    return 0;
}
```

One of the main things making me reluctant to split my programs into many small organized classes rather than a few messy huge ones is the hassle of passing every single variable that one class might need from another. Being able to access variables without having to pass them (and having to update both declarations and definitions should something change) would be very convenient and would let me code more modually.

Any other solutions to my issue would also be appreciated, as I suspect there may be something dangerous about trying to access variable this way.

Comment: `MyClass1::x` doesn't exist without a `MyClass1` instance. So there's no variable to access and your question makes no sense. I think you don't understand classes.

Comment: Would it be possible to let get_x() assume that one istance of MyClass1 exists?

Comment: Research the `friend` and `public` keywords.

Comment: No, it would have to refer to an existing instance. It can't "assume" anything.

Comment: .If MyClass2 derived from MyClass1, then it would have an x if instantiated.

Comment: It would be the exact antithesis of more modular.

Comment: Get back in your kennel!

Comment: You don't have to pass the object variables, you could just pass in references to the objects, especially when there is a synergetic relationship between the two (or more) classes.  Many design patterns actually utilize other objects in their constructors and methods, e.g. a view's Draw method takes a Rectangle object (and also an overload of Draw that takes 4 integers: top, left, bottom, right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can get access to the `x` of `MyClass1` is if you have an instance of that class, because `x` is not `static`.

```
class MyClass2
{
public:
    MyClass2(MyClass1* c1) : myC1(c1) {}
    int get_x()
    {
        return myC1->x;
    }
private:
    MyClass1* myC1;
}
```

Then you can use this like

```
int main()
{
    MyClass1 obj1;
    obj.x = 5;
    MyClass2 obj2{&obj1};
    std::cout << obj2.get_x();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ..or MyClass2 derives from MyClass1.

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't want to assume any inheritance that the OP didn't suggest exists

Comment: Sure - the question is so out-of-it that I was suggesting anything that came to mind:)

Comment: I see, so the simplest thing is just to give classes that need to access each other from outside each other's scope a pointer to the other?

Comment: @KaiSchmidt That is one way to do it, it really depends on the specific case. Maybe one class should **own** an instance of the other. Maybe one class **derives** from the other. Maybe one class merely **refereces/points** to the other. These all depend on what the classes do and how your software is designed.